# Doctrine Relations in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a question for bulding entity classes with doctrine and designing a database in mysql.

Here is a Image whitch shows the entity classes in PHP like they should be.
[PHP Entity Classes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTHS9.png)

But how i have to design this i mysql?
Mysql could not save whole objects. Instead mysql will only store the ids from the objects in the table "supermarket" i think. But is that true?

So how i have to design the mysql tables?

Comment: After you create entity via console, add relationship between entities. Read more: [association mapping](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to design the mysql tables.

You have to design your entities, and relation between them (follow walkingRed link), and Doctrine take care of mysql

Reading about entities : http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#what-are-entities

Symfony doc about doctrine : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

You have to change the way of you thinking, not database tables, but entities.

In you case, 4 entities, with relation.